# sumproduct function with nested if function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Sumproduct formula that counts the number of times a month & year appears within a range, and criteria in cell L3 is found in another column.

This works well enough and is as follows

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(Data!$L$5:$L$6000,"mmyyyy")=TEXT(B10,"mmyyyy"))*(Data!$N$5:$N$6000=$L$3))
```

The criteria in cell L3 could be value a,b,c etc, but it also has an "All" option.

What I can't get it to do is return a count when **all** is selected.  I've tried adding a nested IF statement after the * as follows

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(Data!$L$5:$L$6000,"mmyyyy")=TEXT(B10,"mmyyyy"))*(IF(L3="All",Data!$N$5:$N$6000<>"",Data!$N$5:$N$6000=$L$3)))
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: do the IF outside the SUMPRODUCT with two different SUMPRODUCTS inside.  One like above and the other without the Second Boolean.

Comment: Simple is always the best way!  I got that lost inside the Sumproduct that I forgot to use a straightforward IF statement.  Many thanks for pointing that out for me, it's been a long day :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, following Scott's advice, I've used the following formula which does the job.

```
=IF($D$2="All",SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(Data!$L$5:$L$6000,"mmyyyy")=TEXT(E10,"mmyyyy"))*(Data!$N$5:$N$6000<>"")),SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(Data!$L$5:$L$6000,"mmyyyy")=TEXT(E10,"mmyyyy"))*(Data!$N$5:$N$6000=$L$3)))
```

Hope somebody finds this useful.

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(L:L, ">"&EOMONTH(B10, -1), L:L, "<"&EOMONTH(B10, 0)+1, N:N, IF($L$3="all", "<>", L3))` may be more efficient.